# Get Cognito token using Insomnia with awscognitotoken plugin

Tags: token, amazon-cognito, insomnia, awscognitotoken

I look for the **Authorization token** used by **Cognito** in order to put it in the header of my tests. I need to test some backend API.

I am using Insomnia and the [`awscognitotoken` plugin](https://insomnia.rest/plugins/insomnia-plugin-aws-cognito-token). However, I fail to configure it in order to get the token. Their usage is not clear to me.

Here is how I configure the awscognitotoken plugin :

- Function to Perform: AWS Cognito Team - Plugin for insomnia ………
- Username: the email I use to login to cognito; also tried the cognito username (uuid)
- Password: the password
- Region: `eu-west-1`
- ClientId: `3t********************dcl5`
- TokenType: `access`
- ClientSecret: nothing as none is configured

What I get is:

```
Error in getting session: 
{ "request":
  { "method":"post",
    "headers":{
      "content-type":"application/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "x-amz-target":"AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth"
    },
    "body":"{\"AuthFlow\":\"USER_PASSWORD_AUTH\",\"ClientId\":\"3t***dcl5\",\"AuthParameters\":{\"USERNAME\":\"myemail@example.com\",\"PASSWORD\":\"<password>\"}}"},
  "status":400
}
```

Can you spot any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il seems that in my case the problem was that I did not allow the `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` in the settings of AWS.

Here is what I did to allow it:

- Choose your UserPool
- General Settings › App Clients › Show details
- Auth Flows Configuration › **check `Enable username password based authentication (ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)`**

After doing that I've got the token [and I feel stupid].